# Solving for n in the equation $\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{n}+\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{n}+\left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )^{n}=1$

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

> Solving for $n$ in the equation $$\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{n}+\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{n}+\left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )^{n}=1$$

Can anyone show me a numerical method step-by-step to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: LHS is strictly decreasing for all $n\in\Bbb R$, RHS is constant. $\lim_{n\to -\infty} \text{LHS}=+\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \text{LHS}=0^+$, so exactly one solution exists.

Comment: Writing this as $1^n+2^n+3^n=4^n$ is nicer (but does not directly help solving it).

Comment: Are you looking for solutions with $n$ an integer?

Comment: No, $n \approx 1.7305073578576$.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that there is a closed form solution for $n$? Or will numeric methods suffice?

Comment: no - the answer is 1.730507 using solver - but I can't figure it out

Comment: The formula is used to calculate the fractal dimension

Comment: I just need to see / understand the step-by-step solution to solve for n

Comment: The inverse symbolic calculator found nothing about 1.7305073578576.

Comment: https://classes.yale.edu/fractals/RandFrac/Market/TradingTime/Example1/Ex1Step3.html

Comment: There is no reason to think there is a closed form for this solution.  Because $\log(3/4)$ and $\log(1/4)$ are incommensurable.

Comment: So, no one can show me how to solve for n to give 1.730507?

Answer (score 9):

You seem to want the details of a numerical method to find an good approximation for $x$. Here is one way, using the [Newton-Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), which is well-known and uses fewer steps than other famous methods.

We want to find the zeros of

$$f(x)=0.25^x+0.5^x+0.75^x-1$$

(I rearranged the terms to be in ascending order, which satisfies my sense of style. I also changed the fractions to decimals to make it easier to type into a calculator.) We already know from comments and other answers that $x=1$ is too low and $x=2$ is too high. So let's choose the average, $1.5$, as our initial guess $x_0$. We then use the recurrence

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

This is what I typed into my graphing calculator (TI-Nspire CX):

$$x:=1.5$$
$$x:=x-\frac{0.25^x+0.5^x+0.75^x-1}{0.25^x\cdot\ln(0.25)+0.5^x\cdot\ln(0.5)+0.75^x\cdot\ln(0.75)}$$

That gave me the answer
$$1.71161782284$$

which is $x_1$. Repeated presses of the [enter] key repeated the recurrence, and I got

$$1.73037816962$$
$$1.73050735181$$
$$1.73050735786$$
$$1.73050735786$$

More [enter]'s just repeated the last value. Therefore, an excellent approximation to your desired value, probably to $12$ significant digits, is $1.73050735786$.

Comment: Thank Rory - approx is good enough for government work! That's all I need. Many thanks

Comment: easy for me to write the code to - average, iteration - estimate.

Comment: @Rory Daulton It is necessary to prove that the sequence which is obtained from the Newton-Raphson method converges when $x_0 = 1.5$.

Comment: @MathOverview: Who says a proof is necessary? Not the OP. I do know the proof of this, but I grant your point that the bisection method (for example) is much easier to prove as correctly convergent.

Comment: @MathOverview: **O**riginal **P**ost.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I think that to ensure convergence should use some type of [Kantorovich's theorem for Newton methold](https://www.google.com.br/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Kanthorovich&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=9gF2VdX4F-Op8wfozYDADg#channel=fs&q=Kantorovich+type+theorem+convergence+of+Newton+Method) to ensure the convergence of the sequence obtained by Newton's menthold.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Another point which I understand is that you are assuming tacitly that if the method of bisection  converges then Newton-Raphson method converge. You really mean it?

Comment: @MathOverview: No, I mean that under certain simple conditions the bisection method is guaranteed to converge, and the proof is practically the same as that of the Intermediate Value Theorem for continuous functions. The conditions that guarantee convergence for Newton's method are more complicated, as is the proof.

Comment: Here, OP = Original Poster, not Original Post. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/what-does-op-mean

Comment: @RoryDaulton I do not want to be rude. But if it is not proved the convergence of the sequence $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ to $f(x)=0.25^x+0.5^x+0.75^x-1$ and $x_0 = 1.5$ converge then your answer is not correct.

Comment: @MathOverview You can see that it converges by trying it, so it _is_ correct. A proof of convergence can be simplified since there is no extremum of $f$ in $[1,2]$.

Comment: Rory - Did the number appear after just 4 iterations? Or when you say "repeated" did you skip a few? +1 nice solution.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Yes, the number appeared after just $4$ iterations. I showed all the values that appeared on my calculator. That's why I used Newton-Raphson: when it works it works very quickly. It usually doubles the number of correct significant digits, and my first value had one correct significant digit.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x)=\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{x}+\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{x}+\left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )^{x}-1$. Now note that $f(1)=\frac12$ and $f(2)=-\frac18$. Hence given that $$f'(x)=-4^{-x}(3^x \log\frac43+2^x\log 2+\log4)<0$$ there is one unique root in $(1,2)$. The rest is numerics, this could be approximated to $1.73051$.

Comment: I have edited the question per the OP's following comments. The numerics is the subject of the question.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong many thanks, I guess I am a bit late in fine-tuning my answer since there is another excellent and detailed answer to this by R. Daulton.

Answer (score 3):

The function :
$$y=0.25^x+0.5^x+0.75^x-1$$
is decreasing.

For example $y(1)=2$ and $y(2)=-\frac{1}{8}$. So, the root for $y=0$ is  between $x=1$ and $x=2$.

In this case, among many numerical methods, the dichotomic method is very simple. The successives values $x_k$ are :
$$x_{k+1}=x_{k}+\frac{\delta_k}{2^k}$$
where $\delta_k=\pm 1$

the signe is $+$ if $y_k=(0.25^{x_k}+0.5^{x_k}+0.75^{x_k}-1) >0$

the signe is $-$ if $y_k<0$.

ALGORITHM:

$x:=1$

$d:=1$

repeat

$ \quad \quad d:=\frac{d}{2}$

$ \quad \quad y:=0.25^x+0.5^x+0.75^x-1$

$ \quad \quad $ if $y>0$ then $x:=x+d$ else $x:=x-d$

until $d<10^{-15} $

(or another limit depending on the wanted accuracy).

RESULT : $x=1.73050735785763$

Of course, the convergence is slower than with the Newton-Raphson method for example. But, in both casses, the time of computation is so small that this is negligible. On the other hand, the time spent in programming the algorithm is smaller with the dichotomic method : that is the most important point in practice.

Comment: Thank you....much appreciated

Comment: "The time spent in programming" is negligible for Newton-Raphson if you do it on a calculator, as I did, at least if the derivative is easy (as in this case). And isn't your algorithm more commonly called the "Bisection method"?

Comment: I agree with "bisection method". They are other terms :  binary search or half-interval search. I don't know what name is the more appropriate. I will not argue about the time of programmation. This depends of the avalaible software. I also use commonly the Newton-Raphson or other methods depending of the cases.

Comment: @JJacquelin Bisection method appears to be more standard in mathematical literature. (Binary search is more common in CS related topics and I've never heard of "dichotomic method")

Comment: @ AlexR : OK. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @AlexR: *dichotomic* is also very common. By the Greek etymology, "cutting in two".

Comment: @JJacquelin: the time spent in programming is not really relevant, because these methods are so simple (they can fit in a single line of code) and the code is written once for all. There is a more serious difference: the dichotomic search and also the important secant/regula falsi methods do not require the computation of the derivative, while Newton does. This can make a true difference when the derivative is complicated or pathologic.

Comment: @Yves Daoust : I fully agree. I suppose that, for James who raised the question, he has no code ready made and he likes better to write a code as simple as possible. In addition, note that, when the analytical axpression of the derivative is too complicated, one can compute it numericaly (approximately of course) with a very small variation of the variable : a few lines of code in addition, simpler than writting complicate formulas.

Answer (score 1):

A non-standard approach to get an approximate solution:

Notice that the sum $$\frac14\left(\frac120.00^n+0.25^n+0.50^n+0.75^n+1.00^n\frac12\right)$$ is the five-points trapezoidal approximation of
$$\int_0^1t^ndt=\frac1{n+1}.$$
So,

$$f(n)=0.25^n+0.50^n+0.75^n\approx\frac4{n+1}-\frac12.$$
Hence, $f(n)=1$ when
$$n\approx\frac53=1.66666\cdots.$$
Note that
$$f(\frac53)=1.033304\cdots,$$not so bad.

Comment: This is indeed an intereting use of the trapezoidal method !

Answer (score 0):

There is no analytic solution for this problem. However, the LHS is monotonic, and as such easy to solve numerically using your method of choice.

Comment: I have edited the question per the OP's following comments. The numerics is the subject of the question.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers already mentioned, we can notice that $f(1)=\frac12$ and  $f(2)=-\frac18$ which mean that, more than likely, the solution is rather close to $x_0=2$. If we start Newton method at this point, the successive iterates are $$x_1=1.703616841$$ $$x_2=1.730245725$$ $$x_3=1.730507333$$ $$x_4=1.730507358$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures. You can notice that we have one overshoot of the solution because the iterations started at a point $x_0$ for which $f(x_0)f''(x_0) <0$.

It can be woth to mention that the convergence to the solution could be faster using higher order iterative methods. For example, starting at $x_0=2$, using Halley  method (cubic convergence) the first iterate would be $1.733482269$ while using Householder method (quartic convergence) the first iterate would be $1.730170949$.

**Edit**

As Peter answered , the problem could be reset as $$f(x)=4^x-(1+2^x+3^x)$$ which is a very stiff function. However, if we consider instead $$g(x)=x\log(4)-\log(1+2^x+3^x)$$ the function is much more linear. Starting again Newton method at $x_0=2$, the successive iterates will now be $$x_1=1.722964808$$ $$x_2=1.730501219$$ $$x_3=1.730507358$$

You could also be interested by the fact that, expanding $g(x)$ as a Taylor series built at $x=2$ and limiting to second order, the solution of the quadratic equation gives an estimate which is $\approx 1.730171694 $.

Comment: a typical answer of yours :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust. I am really afraid that this is true ! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Classic problem for Newton's Method.

Note that $F(n) = \dfrac{1}{2^n} + \dfrac{1}{4^n} + \dfrac{3^n}{4^n}-1$ is continuously differentiable.  Furthermore, $F(0) = 2$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F(n) =-1$ so by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is definitely a zero.

I used Maple to calculate the root to a tolerance of $10^{-15}$ because I can.

```
with(Student[NumericalAnalysis]):
F(z):= n-> 1/2^n + 1/4^n + 3^n/4^n:


Newton(F(z),n=0.2,tolerance=10^-15)
>>>1.73050735785764
```

Answer (score -1):

$\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{n}+\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{n}+\left ( \frac{3}{4} \right )^{n}= \frac{2^n}{4^n} +\frac{1^n}{4^n} +\frac{3^n}{4^n} = \frac{1^n+2^n+3^n}{4^n}=1,\: \therefore 1^n+2^n+3^n=4^n  $

I don't think this can be solved analytically,
you just have to use trial and error with n

Comment: Thanks for that - however, that's a problem as I wanted to code an algo to do it.....maybe there is a way.